# Image Not Appearing on Timeline when Website is Liked, Inconsistently works in Linter

Tags: web, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall

I am creating a website for my church, and am fairly inexperienced at html.  However, I have managed to get the Like button to work with the exception of getting the image to load on the timeline.  I run the linter tool and sometimes it shows the image, sometimes it doesn't.  Here are my meta tags:

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Burnt Chimney United Methodist Church" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Burnt Chimney, Church, United Methodist" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Burnt Chimney United Methodist Church" />
<meta property="og:type" content="non_profit" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.gbgm-umc.org/fbcumc/fb_outside.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.gbgm-umc.org/fbcumc/index.html" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Burnt Chimney UMC" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="cline.m.a" />
</head>
```

The Linter tool consistently gives this warning:

> The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Every once in a while it gives this warning:

> The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded

I'm using the iframe version of the Like button I created using the Like Button creation tool.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you didn't use fbml in your script, because fbml is not supported to facebook, u can call php API instead of fbml.

this is not happened with the meta or content tag, u canl call call google api to load ur script.

this is necessary from Facebook to call any API of Facebook to run the script.

https://www.facebook.com/Usiipage/app_429241580427755

SEE THIS fangetting APP.

Comment: What do I have to do to call the correct API?  I don't think I have any fbml since I got the code for the Like button from the like button creator from the facebook developer website.